# Project Server Web App Database Provisioning failed

Tags: project-server

I have successfully configured Project Server Service Application on my SharePoint 2013 machine, I am using SharePoint 2013 SP1 and SQL Server 2014 Enterprise.

When I create a Project Server Web, Database provisioning fails and I get the following error in Event Log

```
Failed to provision site PWA with error: 

Microsoft.Office.Project.Server.Administration.ProvisionException: Failed to provision database.
Database provisioning failed. The database WSS_Content_ProjectWebApp contains a non project schema and cannot be used. ---> Microsoft.Office.Project.Server.Administration.ProvisionException: Database provisioning failed. The database WSS_Content_ProjectWebApp contains a non project schema and cannot be used.
   at Microsoft.Office.Project.Server.Administration.PsiServiceApplication.EnsureProjectServiceDatabase(ProjectProvisionSettings provset, String collation, ProjectDatabaseStateType& originalDatabaseState)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Office.Project.Server.Administration.PsiServiceApplication.EnsureProjectServiceDatabase(ProjectProvisionSettings provset, String collation, ProjectDatabaseStateType& originalDatabaseState)
   at Microsoft.Office.Project.Server.Administration.PsiServiceApplication.CreateSite(ProjectProvisionSettings provset)
```

Comment: Are you referencing an existing database by accident?

Comment: No, I am creating new one from Project Server Service Application's page

Comment: If you specify the database to `PWA_TEST_CONTENT`, what happens?

Answer (score 0):

This error message `"Database provisioning failed. The database WSS_Content_ProjectWebApp contains a non project schema and cannot be used.`" is guiding me that you are using an existing database.

Please make sure when you provision a new PWA, you should create a new database.Looks like this "WSS_Content_ProjectWebApp" this db is faulty.

Try a different name and then try to provision it.

Answer (score 0):

in my case provisioning error was related to **Web Service Root** application pool stopped in some servers in farm in IIS

1- first run below command

```
Upgrade-SPProjectWebInstance -Identity "http://epm.domain.com/pwa"
```

2- if like my case you see similar to following error, just go to server and find related application pool and start it and try again

```
Upgrade-SPProjectWebInstance : The HTTP service located at
http://servername:32843/SecurityTokenServiceApplication/securitytoken.svc is
unavailable.  This could be because the service is too busy or because no
endpoint was found listening at the specified address. Please ensure that the
address is correct and try accessing the service again later
```

3- After previous step, Upgrade-SPProjectWebInstance ran successfully and provisioning error gets resolved